# Firebase query where by sub-collection field

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore structure like this.

[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyfMT.jpg)

Question 1: I want to query all channels by their title. Can you provide assistance? I expected to get news collection.

Question 2: How can I search for news collection whose titles contain keywords across all channels provided by the user? Could you please guide me on this?